# Using Azure Mobile App to authenticate Nancy

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I see that I can add Nancy to my Azure Mobile App. http://www.strathweb.com/2014/02/running-owin-pipeline-new-net-azure-mobile-services/ but how can I add the authentication for Nancy? The goal here is to be able to have both a web app and a mobile app using the same server.

**Goal**: If Nancy page requires authentication, jump to ~/.auth/login/aad (for example), then return to the originating page.

**Where I am:**

1. Created new Azure Mobile App ASP.NET application
2. Added Nancy
3. Remove default MobileAppConfig and replace with

   ```
       new MobileAppConfiguration()
           .MapApiControllers()
           .AddTables(
               new MobileAppTableConfiguration()
                   .MapTableControllers()
                   .AddEntityFramework()
           )
           .AddPushNotifications()
           .MapLegacyCrossDomainController()
           .ApplyTo(config);
   ```
4. Create an IndexModule and confirm that Nancy works

   ```
   public IndexModule()
   {
       Get["/"] = _ => "Hello";
   }
   ```
5. Create an AdminModule, RequiresAuthentication comes after installing Nancy.Authentication.Forms

   ```
   public AdminModule()
       : base("admin")
   {
       Get["/"] = _ =>
       {
           this.RequiresAuthentication();
           return "This is admin";
       };
   }
   ```
6. Probably the wrong thing to do, but I have

   ```
   protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoCContainer container, NancyContext context)
   {
       base.ConfigureRequestContainer(container, context);
       container.Register<IUserMapper, UserMapper>();
   }

   protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
   {
       base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);

       var formsAuthConfig = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration
       {
           RedirectUrl = "~/.auth/login/aad",
           UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>(),
       };

       FormsAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, formsAuthConfig);
   }
   ```

This sends the user to the right auth page, but when zumo returns it (1) returns to a callback with token, and (2) gives a link to "website" that is the main site, rather than the returnUrl, and (3) still doesn't really work.

**Update.** Looks like Nancy.Forms.Authentication is a deadend on this. Can I use `UseCookieAuthentication` from Owin.Security?

**Update2.** I got rid of Nancy.Forms.Authentication. It looks like when Zumo finishes authenticating, the owin server.user is actually set.

```
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

        Csrf.Enable(pipelines);
        pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(FlowPrincipal);
    }

    private Response FlowPrincipal(NancyContext context)
    {
        var env = Get<IDictionary<string, object>>(context.Items, NancyMiddleware.RequestEnvironmentKey);
        if (env != null)
        {
            var principal = Get<IPrincipal>(env, "server.User") as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (principal != null)
            {
                context.CurrentUser = new ClaimsPrincipalUserIdentity(principal);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Will give a valid useable user. How to trigger login and redirect is another question though.

**Update3.** I was able to force login using the setting in Azure

[image]

And surprisingly this also takes care of the redirect. Not sure how it affects SignalR/Zumo tables, but hopefully it will be able to check for the header and not force login on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post you reference is for Azure Mobile Services, not Azure Mobile Apps.

Check out chapter 6 of my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook.  It explicitly shows you how to handle App Service Authentication for a variety of platforms.  Nancy isn't one of them directly, but the MVC version should assist you there.

Comment: Adrian, I tried using Nancy.Authentication.Forms but using the zumo .auth login. However, zumo does not appear to respect "returnUrl" besides not quite working.

Comment: Interesting - hate to point you elsewhere, but you should post this (preferably with a link to a simple repo) to the Azure Forums : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc - this will then get seen by the appropriate people.  Unfortunately, there isn't a GitHub repo to file an issue on this.

Comment: Adrian, I will need your help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643203/when-using-azure-ad-b2c-with-azure-mobile-apps-how-is-the-password-policy-set - When you create a sign-up or sign-in policy (with local accounts), the consumer will see a "Forgot password?" link on the first page of the experience. Clicking on this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset policy. Instead a specific error code AADB2C90118 is returned back to your app. Your app needs to handle this and invoke a specific password reset policy.  - Since zumo auth sees the error code not sure how to handle it.

Comment: You will need to deal with AAD folks or B2C folks for that - I don't have enough experience to answer.

Comment: Do you know who is in charge of Authentication for Azure Mobile Apps? The code gets sent to .auth/login/aad/callback but then disappears after that. I don't think that code is on github, and is internal to Azure.